# Invalid WSDL error when accessing a web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, netbeans

I'm new with webservices. I am trying to access a webservice in java using netbeans.
I followed some tutorials and created a web application project, then created a web service client. Netbeans created an index.jsp file, where I can access the webservice perfectly, but I want to access the webservice thru a java class. 
I created a java class file where I put the same code I have in the jsp page and I get the error :

> "Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://...... It failed with: 
>       Invalid WSDL http://..... , expected {http://  schemas.xmlsoap. org/wsdl/}definitions found HTML at (lineLine number = 1"

If I debug the jsp page, I get no errors, but I can't compile in java class. I don't understand!
This is my jsp code that works perfectly:

```
<%-- start web service invocation --%>
<%
try {
    com.epq.tipocambio.TipoCambio service = new com.epq.tipocambio.TipoCambio();
    com.epq.tipocambio.TipoCambioSoap port = service.getTipoCambioSoap();
    com.epq.tipocambio.InfoVariable result = port.tipoCambioDia();
    Float cambio = result.getCambioDolar().getVarDolar().get(0).getReferencia();
    out.println("Cambio = " + cambio);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //TODO handle custom exceptions here
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
%>
```

And this is my java class code that is giving me the errors:

```
package com.epq.tipocambio;

public class EPQTipoCambioDia {
    private static InfoVariable tipoCambioDia() {
        com.epq.tipocambio.TipoCambio service = new com.epq.tipocambio.TipoCambio();
        com.epq.tipocambio.TipoCambioSoap port = service.getTipoCambioSoap();
        return port.tipoCambioDia();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        InfoVariable c = EPQTipoCambioDia.tipoCambioDia();
        Float cambio = c.getCambioDolar().getVarDolar().get(0).referencia;
        System.out.print(cambio);
    }
}
```

Any Ideas of what could be the problem?

Comment: Try moving the code of tipocambiodia to main. Maybe there's some context implicit and related to service object lifetime

Comment: I tried what you said, but nothing, same error

Comment: The error mentions that the WSDL is invalid.  Can you post a sample that exemplifies the issue at hand?

Comment: The webservice Im trying to consume is from a bank. This is the wdsl definition: [link](http://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx?wsdl)
The only thing I see here is that there's no service name defined at first, but it doesn't stops my jsp page to consume it